# Do you know cloud storage supporting restriction to many folders by different domain?

Tags: amazon-s3, cloud

We are looking for reliable cloud storage which have a function to set restriction to access  files in folder for requests from predefined domains? For example:

I can download file by url http://cool-storage.com/resource-folder1/file.bin from sites http://mywebsite.com and http://yourwebsite.com. But I can't download file.bin from site http://theirsite.com.

We tried to use Amazon S3, but it has this functionality only for bucket, not to folders or files inside it. Also Amason S3 has limit to bucket creation.

Has anyone similar task?

Thanks

Comment: Link does not wirk @Viccari

Comment: @ShailenSukul yes. Since I could not find the original question anymore, I removed my comment.